# fgetc() vs fscanf("%s") to get strings from a txt file in c programming

Tags: c, fgets, scanf, fgetc

I'm new to programming and C is my first language. I have an assignment in which the first part was to take user input and write it as strings to a text file. The second part, which must be a new code is to get the lines of text from the file and display them as separate strings.

I have looked on the forums and see some people using fgets() and some using fgetc(), but I'm a bit confused as to which one would suit this situation better. For example the code I have so far, where file.txt has 3 lines of text

```
potato
turkey
cranberry_sauce
```

Would return

```
"  "
"  "
potato
```

If I add another string it ends up grabbing nothing. Am I even going down the right path??
Thanks all for any suggestions, I really appreciate it.

The code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

const int L = 80;
int main(void)
{
    char string1[L], string2[L], string3[L];
    FILE *pfile = NULL;
    pfile = fopen("file.txt",  "r");

    fscanf(pfile,"%s%s%s", &string1, &string2, &string3);

    printf("%s\n", string3 );
    printf("%s\n", string2 );
    printf("%s\n", string1 );
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: dropping the & when getting the strings wprked. Thanks a bunch all!

Comment: remove the c++ tag before the police comes! :P

Comment: Shhhh... We can do this silently. No one needs know.

Comment: `fscanf` returns a count of how many items it read. In this case if it's not three, the read failed.

Comment: But the first thing to do is check that `pfile` isn't NULL after opening. If it's NULL, use `perror` to find out why.

Comment: `fscanf(pfile,"%s %s %s", string1, string2, string3)`; // no &

Comment: Yeah. Compiler should have caught that. Recommend turning on the warnings and trying to resolve them. Compiler error means bad syntax. Can't build program. Compiler warning usually means check your logic.  Can build program but it probably doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: @user4581301 Compiler should have caught what? An error in a format string? That's not what compilers do.

Comment: @EJP I'm so used to seeing compilers that do check the format string I'd forgotten it wasn't required. I stand down.

Comment: @EJP That's what good modern compilers do. A compiler is not required to do that, but it is not required to do anything useful at all. As far as diagnostic is concerned, it can say just "Your program has an error" if any error is present and still be 100% conforming.